# Swift using NSLocale for date formatter - need to set country automatically

Tags: iphone, swift, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I have found the below example and it seems to work in both am-pm mode and 24 hour mode.

The problem is I want to set the locale identifier automatically depending on the user's country.
I did not find a list with the countries or a method to do it automatically.

Can anyone help with an example?

```
let mydate = "2014-10-28T18:14:32"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
if let parsedDateTimeString = formatter.dateFromString(mydate) {
    formatter.stringFromDate(parsedDateTimeString)
    print(parsedDateTimeString)
} else {
    print("Could not parse date")
}
```

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720060/nsdate-independent-of-timezone) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "user's country". If you would like to get the locale identifier the device is currently set to try `NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier`.

Comment: for example if the hour is 18:14:32 in my country it should be displayed as 21:14:32

Comment: For that you need to look more into NSDate and how to deal with timezones.

Answer (score 0):

have a try below code. It works for me.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: time)
```

According to Apple's [Formatting Data Using the Locale Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html)